# Parse KML with prefix (colon) into json

Tags: json, parsing, google-maps-api-3, kml

I have some KML files created by Google My Tracks.
I would like to covert it in json format so I can access specific point of time and place.
However, the KML markups has prefixes (e.g. `<gx:SimpleArrayField>` and `<gx:coord>`) which cause problems while parsing with "xml2json". xml2json just wont recognize gx:coord even if I try to use `$('gx\\:coord')` to escape.

Also, inside  has three values (longitude, latitude, and altitude) and they are separeted by space only (it looks like `<gx:coord>-73.994146 40.735471 13.800000190734863</gx:coord>`) how can I separete those into three different elements?

Does anyone have recommended parser or solution for this? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just realized instead of calling the elements by it's full original name (ex: `<gx:coord>`) I just have to call it with its shortened name after the colon. (ex: `<coord>`) after parsing with xmltojson.